# Debezium mongodb connector to only work with secondary db

Tags: debezium

i am using debezium-mongodb-connector(1.6) for capturing cdc events i want the connector to use against secondary db when i use it against secondary db it is looking for primary db and giving this "Unable to connect to primary node of 'REPLICASET/HOST:27017' " error

my primary node and secondary node in different vpc and the debezium connector is only exposed to secondary node and i don't want the connector to give any load to primary node

is there any way to achive this??

Thanks

Mike